# ModelStateDictionairy Malformed json web api

Tags: c#, .net, json, asp.net-core, .net-core

Im using the modelstate property to check if my model is valid.
It all works well however when i add more properties (which do not exist in my model) to my json body it says the model is still valid.

How would one check the json body sent to match the C# model?

This is my model for now:

```
public class User
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string IdentityServerId { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Email is required")]
        [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "Not a valid emailaddress")]
        public string Email { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Name is required")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    }
```

The correctly formatted json would be:

```
{
    "Name": "Klaas",
    "Email": "eifjelfij@sdf"
}
```

This gives a 200 OK which creates the corresponding user.

However when i'm sending this json:

```
{
    "Name": "Arjan",
    "Email": "eifjelfij@sdf",
    "eifj":"eflijelfij"
}
```

It still creates the user but i'd love to give the user an error message instead of user creation.

Comment: The lower one is valid json too, because you don't have a property `eifj` so it will effectively be discarded. Model validation can only validate properties which well... exist on the model ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the JSON.NET settings during application startup to handle non-existing properties as error...

```
services.AddMvc()
    .AddJsonOptions(options =>
    {
        options.SerializerSettings.MissingMemberHandling = MissingMemberHandling.Error;
    });
```

This should result in that your `User` parameter in the controller action will be `null`, which results in a validation failure.

And in your Action you could handle it specially too.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody]Models.User user)
{
    if(!ModelState.IsValid) 
    {
        if(user==null)
        {
            // user is null, which means we couldn't deserialize it or 
            // no data was sent with the request
            return BadRequest(new { Error = "Invalid formatted data." });
        }

        // return errors, since we know user is not null
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }
}
```

Comment: This was exactly what i needed! This simplifies it a lot hahah

Answer (score 1):

Convert the JSON into your user object, and then use reflection to check if any of your User objects properties are null. Try this:

```
User user = CreateUserFromJson(json); // assuming user object already created by you
if (TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(user).Cast<PropertyDescriptor>().Any(prop => prop.GetValue(user) == null))
{
// json is missing fields
}
```

Comment: Hmm is there no default way for this?
This would indicate that i first have to deserialize my json response (which is responsibility of mvc imho) and then check the props if they match the ones in my model. It's okay this is what i'm doing right now indeed but i'd have thought maybe `aspnet` or `newtonsoft json` had something for this already..

Currently within the controller i'm retrieving the data like this: `public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody] Models.User user)
        {//do stuff}`

Comment: not that im familiar with. You could probably create your own JSON deserializer that extends Newtonsoft and then implement this json string check in there before you call the parent function to actually deserialize the json